# why is web scraping with Robobrowser in Python causing "Task was destroyed but it is pending!"

Tags: python, bots, discord, robobrowser

I'm writing code for a Discord bot which searches different game hosting sites. It searches for an image and a description in the html of the page using Robobrowser.

Before, I had no issue. I just added a case for the Google Play Store, however, and now it's telling me "Task was destroyed but it is pending!" when it tries to get those items through a GPS link.

I don't know why this is happening, nor do I know how to fix it. I looked up all other "Task was destroyed..." cases, but none were similar to mine.

Here is my code:

I've tried threading it and awaiting it. Robobrowser cannot be awaited, so that didn't work. Threading also didn't work because I need the functions to return a string. I know it's possible to return something while using a different thread, but it was overly complex for what I'm trying to fix.

```
def get_embed_caption(url):
    print("Getting caption")
    desc = None
    if url != "No Link":
        try:
            browser.open(url)
            desc = "something"
        except:
            print("Caption ERROR with url")
            desc = None
        if desc != None:
            if "itch.io" in url and " " not in url:
                parse = browser.parsed
                parse = str(parse)

                pos2 = parse.find("og:description")
                pos1 = parse.rfind('content=', 0, pos2)

                desc_type = parse[pos1+8:pos1+9]

                pos2 = parse.rfind(desc_type, 0, pos2-2)
                pos1 = parse.find(desc_type, pos1)
                desc = parse[pos1+1:pos2]

                if len(desc) > 1000:
                    desc = desc[:1000]
                if "/><" in desc:
                    pos = parse.find("formatted_description user_formatted")
                    pos = parse.find("<p>", pos)
                    desc = parse[pos+3:parse.find('</p>', pos)]
            elif "steam" in url and " " not in url:
                parse = browser.parsed
                parse = str(parse)
                pos = parse.find("game_description_snippet")
                pos = parse.find('"', pos)
                pos = parse.find('>', pos)
                desc = parse[pos+1:parse.find('<', pos+1)]
            elif "play.google" in url and " " not in url:
                parse = browser.parsed
                parse = str(parse)
                pos = parse.find('aria-label="Description"')
                print(parse[pos:pos+20])
                pos = parse.rfind("content", 0, pos)
                print(parse[pos:pos+20])
                pos = parse.find('"', pos)
                print(parse[pos:pos+20])
                desc = parse[pos+1:parse.find('"', pos+1)]
            else:
                print("No caption")
                desc = None

            if desc != None:
                desc = desc.replace("<p>", "")
                desc = desc.replace("</p>", "")
                desc = desc.replace("<em>", "`")
                desc = desc.replace("</em>", "`")
                desc = desc.replace("<br>", "")
                desc = desc.replace("<br/>", "")

    return desc
```

```
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<Client._run_event() running at C:\Users\Gman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py:307> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[BaseSelectorEventLoop._sock_connect_done(696)(), <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x0000000005DEAA98>()]>>
```

It seems to run through the process just fine, but right when it finishes, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play Store has a lot of gibberish HTML, probably to make web scraping there difficult on purpose. This led to it taking more than 10 seconds to parse the page. I do not know what caused the task to destroy itself, however.

The fix was to use Python's play-scraper library, which was 20x faster, taking less than half a second to gather the info.